# Testify whether values of one table exists in another table

Tags: cognos

I've created a new query and added a new data item to it. The data item is of `Boolean` type. I'd like to write an `"if... else..."` expression to define it. If a data in `table1.field1` exists in `table2.field2`, it returns "Yes". Otherwise, it returns "No". My question is, how to write the "if" expression?

I've tried both:

```
"(table1.field1) in (table2.field2)"
```

and

```
"(table2.field2) contains (table1.field1)"
```

but neither of them can pass the format validation.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is in report Studio? In your data item expression window, you look in the `f(x)` tab under the 'constructs' folder you'll find the format for `if then else`

```
IF ( <condition> ) THEN
    ( <expression> )
ELSE 
    ( <expression> )
```

You'll need something like

```
IF ( [Field1] LIKE '%' || [Field1] || '%' ) THEN
    ( 'Y' )
ELSE 
    ( 'N' )
```